# TinyMCE in ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, tinymce, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use TinyMCE with ASP.NET MVC 5, however, it does not seem to work. The textarea appears, but it's a regular textarea, not enriched with TinyMCE functionality.

**Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<script src="~/Content/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "editorHtml",
    });
</script>
```

**Views\MyView\Create.cshtml**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Corpo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control editorHtml" } })
```

Any tips?

Comment: Did you check your JavaScript console to see if there were any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current view code is producing output like this

```
<textarea cols="20" htmlattributes="{ class = form-control editorHtml }"
                                         id="Corpo" name="Corpo" rows="2"></textarea>
```

This does not looks correct. It did not add the css classes you wanted, instead it added a new attribute called `htmlAttributes`! Why ? because you used the helper method in an incorrect way!

So fix the bad code in your helper method call. The second parameter takes a single anonymous object.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Corpo, new { @class = "form-control editorHtml" } )
```

This should generate the correct html code for the text area (check view source of the page).

Now your existing code to initialize the rich text editor will work. Alternatively you may use the Id selector as well.

```
<script>

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#Corpo"
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Correct Shyju. I should not have used `htmlAttributes`.